# According to Madhwists - what transgressions would cast someone into Andhatamas?

Tags: madhwa

Andhatamas is approximately "eternal hell" - the Jivatma cast into Andhatamas can never escape through rebirth into a better station.

What are the sins Madhwists regard as leading to Andhatamas?

Is criticizing Madhwa's teachings one of those sins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is criticizing Madhwa's teachings one of those sins?

Yes.

[Citing from the Madhvamrutha maharnava of Sri Narayana Panditacharya](https://gurucharana.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/madwaamruthamaharnava/) ; A work from one of the direct disciples of Sri Madhvacharya.

> [11] If one leaves the MadhwaShaastra and instead goes and studies
> Adhvaitha, then that person is willingly entering the deepest and
> goriest of all hells, ie the andhatamas.
>
> 12] If one follows maayavaada ie advaitha, then andhatamas is
> guaranteed for him, and if the person rejects advaitha and crictisises
> it, then for that person moksha is assured.
>
> [22] **If one crictisises the MadhwaShaastra and instead goes and
> studies Adhvaitha, then that person is willingly entering the deepest
> and goriest of all hells, ie the andhatamas.**
>
> 75] **Those who crictisise Madhwashaastra either by action, mind,speech
> they go to andhatamas. Those who scold such people go to moksha
> without a doubt.**
>
> [86] How much more can be told on this topic, all the vedas and
> puranas mention the same that the devotees of Shri Madhwacharyaru go
> to moksha and those who study maayavaada go to andhatamas.